# Exclude only tailing space character from regex match

Tags: regex

I am trying to select only the the street / unit number from an address string.

My regex pattern is `/^[\d\s,\-\/]*/`

Currently my regex matches `digits` `'/'` `'-'` and `space characters` before any alphabetic characters. However I would like to exlude the tailing `space character`.

My regex matches

`61/2`Sydney Road, Manly NSW (note the space character after the '2')

Instead of

`61/2` Sydney Road, Manly NSW

---

Here are some sample addresses strings:

`61/2 Sydney Road, Manly NSW`

`61-2 Sydney Road, Manly NSW`

`61/2 3 Sydney Road, Manly NSW`

Comment: Can't you just `trim` afterwards?

Comment: If the expected match always ends with a digit, just add the `\d` at the end: [`^[\d\s,\/-]*\d`](https://regex101.com/r/Dk7lwG/1).

Comment: @SebastianProske I didn't think of that -_- easy fix. Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes always will end on a digit. Thanks that works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your expected matches are not empty string (and your current expression - `/^[\d\s,\-\/]*/` - matches empty strings if there is no `[\d\s,\-\/]*` pattern match at the start of the string) and there is always a digit at the end of the match, you may add `\d` at the end of your pattern:

```
/^[\d\s,\/-]*\d/
             ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dk7lwG/1).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `[\d\s,\/-]*` - zero or more digits, whitespaces, `,`, `/` or `-` (note there is no need to escape the hyphen when it is located at the very end of the character class)
- `\d` - a digit.